# Generic type inferred from default argument

Tags: kotlin, generics

```kotlin
fun <T: Comparable<T>> processStuff(
    priority: (Stuff) -> T = { 0 },
) { ... }

processStuff()

processStuff { it.name }
```

The function should treat all stuff equally by default, but there should also be the option to specify the priority function.

Is there sleek (e.g. without overloading) way to achieve that? Also, why isn't that possible anyway? There shouldn't be a difference in doing

```kotlin
fun <T: Comparable<T>> processStuff(
    priority: (Stuff) -> T,
) { ... }

processStuff { 0 }
```

or

```kotlin
fun <T: Comparable<T>> processStuff(
    priority: (Stuff) -> T = { 0 },
) { ... }

processStuff()
```

, should there? Why does the former one work but the latter doesn't?

Comment: If we make a function generic, that basically means the caller controls `T`. `T` could be anything, e.g, `String` and then your default value doesn't conform to requirements. What we would actually like to do instead is not to make the function generic but simply say the `priority` has to return values that are comparable to themselves, so something like: `fun processStuff(priority: (Stuff) -> Comparable<Self> = { 0 })`. Unfortunately, I don't know a way to achieve this in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former case works as it's the same as `processStuff<Int> { 0 }` (`<Int>` type is inferred from `0` so we can skip it). Similarly you could write `processStuff { "a" }` that would be the same as `processStuff<String> { "a" }`

The latter case doesn't work as the `priority`'s return type is specified as `(Stuff) -> T`, but `0` is not always `T`. As in the paragraph above, `T` can be specified as `String` when calling the function (`processStuff<String>()`), and in this case `0` can't be returned.

If you need exactly these constraints, looks like overloading is the "sleekest" way:

```
fun processStuff() {
    processStuff { 0 }
}
```